# Request's RouteData is empty on Ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have an application where I've localized requests based on sent locale. For example: /en/MyController/MyAction. Then I check for sent locale:

```
        if (request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["locale"] != null)
        {
            locale = request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["locale"].ToString();
        }

        return locale;
```

That works fine, except for (it seems) Ajax calls. When I make an AJAX call via my custom Ajax form HTML helper request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["locale"] is null even though Glimpse shows route is matched as it should:

```
 {locale}/MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

My Form HTML Helper

```
    public static MvcForm BeginFormLocalized(this AjaxHelper ajax, string action, object routeValues, AjaxOptions options)
    {
        RouteValueDictionary routeDictionary = UrlHelpers.BuildLocalizedRouteValuesDictionary(ajax.ViewContext.RequestContext, routeValues);
        routeDictionary.Add("action", action);
        string routeName = UrlHelpers.GetAppropriateRouteName(routeDictionary);

        return ajax.BeginRouteForm(routeName, routeDictionary, options);
    }
```

BuildLocalizedRouteValuesDictionary adds locale to RouteValuesDictionary if its present in request and GetAppropriateRouteName returns route name according to route values (localized area, localized default or default route).

Url is generated fine with locale included and also invokes the corrent action but RouteData collection is empty and causes localization to fallback to default locale.

Any ideas? I've tried searching everything I could think of but couldn't find a similar issue.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?